# The existence of conjunctive/disjunctive normal forms?

Tags: reference-request, logic, propositional-calculus

I am studying propositional logic/calculus and I am currently learning about normal forms. The algorithm to construct a conjunctive/disjunctive normal form from any given formula is straightforward. I analyzed some examples via truth/semantic tables but it's still not very clear to me why this works i.e. why are the conjunctive/disjunctive normal form versions of a given formula equivalent to the original formula.

> Could you recommend a book(s)/website/... where I could find a proof about the equivalence of a formula and it's conjunctive/disjunctive normal form (or maybe provide a proof here)?

I would very much appreciate a proof in terms of "interpretations" where an interpretation is every mapping from the set of all propositional variables to the set $\{0,1\}$ i. e. $$I : \{P_0, P_1, P_2, ...\} \to \{ 0, 1 \}$$ where $\{P_0, P_1, P_2, ...\} $ is the set (an infinite countable set) of all propositional variables, instead of a proof with truth tables, i.e.  "If we have $n$ variables, we have $2^n$ rows, ... , consider the $i$-th row ...".

Comment: Do you want a proof for each of the rewriting rules that work in terms of interpretations but doesn't mention truth tables? That will be somewhat difficult, because the _definition_ of how an interpretation applies to, say, $\varphi\to\psi$ is usually by looking up the result in a truth table for $\to$, based on what $\varphi$ and $\psi$ produce for the interpretation. It is that truth table that defines how the connective behaves at all.

Answer (score 3):

The procedure to convert a formula into conjunctive (or disjunctive) normal form can be presented in several different ways, but one of them is to do it as a series of small local rewritings:

1. First get rid of all implications by the rule $p\to q \equiv \neg p \lor q$.
2. Then push all negations down to atomic formulas using De Morgan's rules and double-negation elimination.
3. Finally distribute conjuctions over disjunctions or vice versa, depending on which normal form you want.

Convincing oneself that the whole thing works is then just a matter of seeing that each *little* rewriting rule you use along the way take formulas to equivalent formulas.

Answer (score 1):

For a similar discussion, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379804/every-sentence-in-propositional-logic-can-be-written-in-conjunctive-normal-form).

Anyway, if you are looking for additional information, the following links may be useful for you:

- There is a simple proof for the propositional calculus and the conjunctive normal form [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjunctive_Normal_Form_of_Any_Statement).
- There are some useful information in the *Wikipedia*'s entry about [conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form).

The proof simple: it follows exactly the steps described in the answer above.